# Calibre convertion: text goes out of the screen

Tags: epub, calibre, conversion

I just used Calibre to convert [this html document](https://www.supinfo.com/cours/1CPA/chapitres/08-microprocesseur-son-environnement) into an epub. To do that, I first downloaded the chapter using:

```
wget -r --no-parent -k https://www.supinfo.com/cours/1CPA/
```

and then I rename the file to add `.html` extension:

```
cd www.supinfo.com/cours/1CPA/chapitres
cp 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement.html
```

and convert:

```
ebook-convert 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement.html 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement.epub
```

However, the produced `.epub` displays horribly in my Nolim ereader: the lines goes out of the screen:

[image]

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: the original `.html` file had table inside with fixed width, and that's why the text was running out of the screen. The solution: just use the option `--linearize-tables` !

```
ebook-convert 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement.html 08-microprocesseur-son-environnement.epub  --linearize-tables
```